# YouTube Api V3 Insert Video To Playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I want to add a video to playlist, and i use this URL:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key=MY_KEY
```

And this is the Request body:

```
{
  "snippet": {
    "playlistId": "PLy-aWRoARIeVFnbSzxnfTI2lyTbEC0Nek",
    "resourceId": {
      "videoId": "EHkozMIXZ8w",
      "kind": "youtube#video"
    }
  }
}
```

And i am getting this error:

```
"message": "Playlist item id not specified."
```

Any idea what can  be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had same problem. The problem was in using PUT method (as in PlaylistItems: update) instead of required POST.

Answer (score 0):

The url and data seems to be fine. I think the problem lies elsewhere. Did you specify sending json data ? ('Content-Type:  application/json')

Answer (score 0):

Use insert method

POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

with body

```
{
 "snippet": {
  "playlistId": "playlist_id",
  "resourceId": {
   "videoId": "video_id",
   "kind": "youtube#video"
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: As of 2022, YouTube no longer accepts these changes via an API key and throws a 401 error: "API keys are not supported by this API. Expected OAuth2 access token or other authentication credentials that assert a principal. See https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication".